# What does this do ? .split("[^A-Za-z0-9]")

Tags: java

Is it splitting the chain to words or individual characters ?

```
String func(String sen) {
  String[] var = sen.ToLowerCase().split("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
...
```

Comment: It's splitting using any non-alphanumeric character as a delimiter.

Comment: Also, if you use `var` as a variable name, it will be confusing in future when you use `var` as a keyword.

Comment: Run it on a few different strings and see.

Answer (score 1):

This code will split the input string into words using separation as `no-word-character`. Look at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DfI57V/1).

```java
String str = "One_Two_Three";
String[] words = str.toLowerCase().split("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));   // [one, two, three]
```

I recommend simplifying the regular expression to `[^a-z\d]+` because your input string is already lower-case and match the case when two words are separated with more than one character.

But if you want just split words, you can use `case-insensitive-mode` like this:

```java
String str = "One_Two__Three";
String[] words = str.split("(?i)[^a-z\\d]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words);   // [One, Two, Three]
```